# extract time from datetime using javascript

Tags: javascript

how can i extract time from datetime format.

my datetime format is given below.

```
var datetime =2000-01-01 01:00:00 UTC;
```

I only want to get the time `01.00` as `01`

Comment: Do you want to get this from a string or date object ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 73):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

> Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()
>   Returns a string with a locality sensitive representation of the time portion of this date based on system settings.

```
var time = datetime.toLocaleTimeString();
```

Update:

> The new locales and options arguments let applications specify the
>   language whose formatting conventions should be used and customize the
>   behavior of the function. In older implementations, which ignore the
>   locales and options arguments, the locale used and the form of the
>   string returned are entirely implementation dependent.

```
// Depending on timezone, your results will vary
var event = new Date('August 19, 1975 23:15:30 GMT+00:00');

console.log(event.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));
// expected output: 1:15:30 AM

console.log(event.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT'));
// expected output: 01:15:30
```

Answer (score 20):

What about these methods

[new Date().getHours()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp)

[new Date().getMinutes()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getminutes.asp)

For example:

```
 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getHours();
```

***Edited***

Return the hour, according to universal time:

[new Date().getUTCHours()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getutchours.asp)

Example:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getUTCHours();
```

Comment: But that will return the local hours, the OP seems to want the UTC hours from his UTC date

Comment: var time = datetime.toLocaleTimeString();

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative if you want to get the time from a string -

```
var datetime ="2000-01-01 01:00:00 UTC";
var myTime = datetime.substr(11, 2);
alert(myTime) //01
```

Answer (score 6):

with the [moment.j](http://momentjs.com)s library it works in this way:

```js
var result = moment().format('hh');
alert(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var datetime = ("2000-01-01 01:00:00 UTC");
var d1 = new Date(datetime);
var minute = d1.getUTCMinutes();
var hour = d1.getUTCHours();
if(minute > 0)  
     alert(hour+"."+minute);
else
     alert(hour);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZL8t/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var date1 = new Date(1945,10,20, 17,30)
var date2 = new Date(1970,1,8, 12,00)

console.log(date1.getHours() - 8 + (date1.getMinutes()/60))

console.log(date2.getHours() - 8 + (date2.getMinutes()/60))
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done it! It looks like this:

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + " " + new Date().getSeconds() + " seconds");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
var datetime = "2000-01-01 01:00:00 UTC";

var dt = new Date(datetime);
var hr = dt.getUTCHours();
if(hr > 12) {
   hr -= 12;
}
alert(hr);
```

[refer this link also.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Does not work, it does alert `2` for me (in GMT+0100) - the OP wants to get `1`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) like

```
var datetime = new Date("2000-01-01 01:00:00 UTC"); // might not parse correctly in every engine
// or
var datetime = new Date(Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0));
```

then use the [`getUTCHours` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours):

```
datetime.getUTCHours(); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can find a solution here.

```js
let preDateTime = new Date("2022-03-31 22:26:00");
let newTime = preDateTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
let hour = newTime.split(":")[0];
let amPm = newTime.split(" ")[1];
let seconds = newTime.split(":")[2].replace(amPm,'');;

let noAmPm = newTime.replace(amPm,'');
let noAmPmSeconds = noAmPm.replace(":"+seconds,'');
let noSeconds = newTime.replace(":"+seconds,' ');

if(parseInt(hour)<9){
    newTime = "0"+newTime;
    noAmPm = "0"+noAmPm
    noSeconds= "0"+noSeconds
    noAmPmSeconds = "0"+noAmPmSeconds;
}

console.log(newTime); //10:26:00 PM
console.log(noAmPm); //10:26:00 
console.log(noSeconds); //10:26 PM
console.log(noAmPmSeconds); //10:26
```